# Novice query about string escaping when passing parameters to an MSI

Tags: string, powershell

Please help. I am trying to do what seems like a very simple thing but for the life of me I can't get it working.

I am trying to run an MSI and pass in some parameters but the spaces in my parameters are causing problems and everything I have tried fails:

```
$CONN_STRING = "Data Source=DATABASE_INSTANCE;Initial Catalog=DATABASE_NAME;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=True"
$InstallLocation = "C:\Data\My Web"

msiexec.exe /qb /i MyInstaller.msi TARGETDIR=$InstallLocation CONNECTION_STRING=$CONN_STRING
```

Any ideas would be very helpful. Non of the examples online appear to solve my problem.

Ok to simplify the problem I am removing all reference to the parameters to prove what works:

```
msiexec.exe /qb /i North.GLN.Installer.msi TARGETDIR="'C:\Data\My Web'"
```

This doesn't work.

```
msiexec.exe /qb /i North.GLN.Installer.msi "TARGETDIR='C:\Data\My Web'"
```

This doesn't work

```
msiexec.exe /qb /i North.GLN.Installer.msi "TARGETDIR='C:\Data\MyWeb'" 
msiexec.exe /qb /i North.GLN.Installer.msi TARGETDIR="C:\Data\MyWeb"
```

Both of these without the space in My Web work fine but my install path has a space

**Update**

My problems seem to be powershell related as this same commands work fine if run directly in the command line.

Comment: Could not just just put single quote inside the double as well? `$InstallLocation = "'C:\Data\My Web'"` should work as well so that the singles remain when the variable is expanded.

Comment: Also it would a good idea to show us what you tried that doesnt work so the community does not cover the same ground

Answer (score 0):

Running legacy exe-applications from within powershell can be tricky.

Try this:

```
 $CONN_STRING = "Data Source=DATABASE_INSTANCE;Initial Catalog=DATABASE_NAME;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=True"
$InstallLocation = '"C:\Data\My Web"'
    $Arguments = @(
        "/qb",
        "/i",
        "MyInstaller.msi",
        "TARGETDIR=$InstallLocation",
        "CONNECTION_STRING=$CONN_STRING"
    )
    $Proc = Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $Arguments -PassThru -Wait
    While(-Not($Proc.HasExited)){Start-Sleep -Seconds 1}
    if($Proc.ExitCode -ne 0) {
        Throw ('Installation failed with errorcode: {0}' -f $Proc.ExitCode)
    }
```

Also I would recommend using full paths to your msi package.

Comment: Thanks Simon. This seems to create the same problem, in that the MSI help window pops open suggesting the format of my parameters is not correct, which was the issue I was having.

Comment: I see, sorry I missunderstood the question. Which program is it that you are installing? I think you have to refer to the manual for that product to find out which options that are available or you can install the MSI package without /qb and using the `switch:/L*V myinstall.log` to generate verbose log. Then seach this log to find out which connection string that was used.

Comment: Ignoring the connection string for a second I can pass TARGETDIR with a path with no spaces and the application installs correctly with a blank connection string.

The problem arises when my path has a string with spaces. Removing all dependency on variables altogether.

Comment: I see, that is fixed by enclosing the path in quotes:
$InstallLocation = '"C:\Data\My Web"'

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting the property=value settings:

```
$CONN_STRING = "Data Source=DATABASE_INSTANCE;Initial Catalog=DATABASE_NAME;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=True"
$InstallLocation = "C:\Data\My Web"
msiexec.exe /qb /i MyInstaller.msi "TARGETDIR=$InstallLocation" "CONNECTION_STRING=$CONN_STRING"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I abandoned powershell in favour of a batch file. Not ideal but I couldn't spend anymore time trying to do the most basic of things.

The command I used is below:

```
SET DATABASE_INSTANCE=SERVERNAME
SET DATABASE_NAME=DBNAME
SET INSTALL_DIRECTORY=INSTALLLOCATION
SET CONN_STRING=Data Source=%DATABASE_INSTANCE%;Initial Catalog=%DATABASE_NAME%;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=True

msiexec.exe /qb /i MyInstaller.msi 
TARGETDIR="%INSTALL_DIRECTORY%" 
CONNECTION_STRING="%CONN_STRING%"
```

Comment: Not necessary (see my answer).